# Good way to close multiple resources across multiple methods

Tags: java

I have a class that uses multiple `Closeable` resources, it opens them in the constructor and I want them to be closed in `close()` (inherited also from `Closeable` interface) method. I want to use this class in a try-with-resources block similar to the `java.io` classes.

Example (this is not actual code, but shows a problem for two resources):

```
public class Foo implements Closeable {
    private final Reader first;
    private final Reader second;

    public Foo(Reader first, Reader second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
```

...

```
    @Override
    public close() throws IOException {
        first.close();
        second.close();
    }

}
```

The above code is not correct, because if `first.close()` throws exception, the `second` won't be closed. Adding try/finally around those is a PITA and if I have even more of those its almost unmanageable.

Basically my question is: Is there a library that does closing of multiple resources and logs the exceptions and throws away the last one found?

I looked at multiple (guava `Closeables`, `IOUtils.closeQuitly()`) but they deal only with one resource, I would like to provide a collection of those.

Comment: Why are you opening them before you actually *need* to open them?

Comment: I'd not open resources in the constructor; it makes testing a pain in the lower end of the back.

Comment: @Makoto I updated the description, I'm getting e.g. Readers (or Streams or Sockets) from outside and I want to close them in close method (as all java.io classes do that this way)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a class something like this:

```
public class Test{

        public static List<Exception> exceptions;
   public static void main(String[] args){  

             exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
             callException("A");
             callException("B");
           for(Exception e:exceptions)
           {
               System.out.println(" "+e);
           }
  }

         public static void callException(String a)
         {
             try
             {
                 if(a.equals("A"))
                     throw new IOException();
                 else
                     throw new NullPointerException(); 
             }
             catch(Exception ioe)
             {
                 exceptions.add(ioe);
             }
         }

}
```

Output:

```
java.io.IOException
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Which is clearly saving all the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but it should work with any number of Readers or other Closable classes

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo implements Closeable {
    private final Reader first;
    private final Reader second;

    private List<Exception> exceptions;

    public Foo() {
        this.exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        this.first = createReader("first.txt");
        this.second = createReader("second.txt");

        printExceptions();
    }

    private Reader createReader(String fileString) {
        try {
            return new FileReader(fileString);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            exceptions.add(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IllegalStateException {
        exceptions.clear();

        closeReader(first);
        closeReader(second);

        printExceptions();

        if (exceptions.size() > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    private void closeReader(Reader reader) {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exceptions.add(e);
        }
    }

    private void printExceptions() {
        for (int i = 0; i < exceptions.size(); i++) {
            exceptions.get(i).printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Robert: True.  You can pick a different exception to throw in the close method.  It's more important to pick up the null values from the constructor.